# OSError: Error no file named model.safetensors found in directory

Tags: huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, huggingface, llama

I am trying to load a LLAMA2 model saved in Hugging Face safe tensors format. The model is saved in two parts model-part1.safetensors and model-part2.safetensors.

I am using LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained() Hugging Face API to load the model.

When I pass the folder containing the model files, I am the following error

`OSError: Error no file named model.safetensors found in directory ..`

The code that I am using is:

```
from transformers import LlamaForCausalLM, LlamaTokenizer
tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained("./tokenizer.model")
model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained('./', use_safetensors=True)
```

How can I load a sharded model using Hugging Face API?

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: Please provide more informations: the link to the model you are using , the full code you using to load the model.
Os the model in your local machine or on Hugging Face safe?

Comment: I am using a custom finetuned LLAMA2 model that is present in my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix. I have tried few things and identified that, we must add

**model.safetensors.index.json** to the folder where the model is saved in Safe tensor format when the model is saved in parts.

Then the model successfully loaded